# Filter the content from a post globally immediately after is fetched from the database

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I am encrypting the content of a specific custom post type whenever i am updating or creating it. That is working fine.

Is there a way to globally decrypt the content for all WordPress read operations either from backend or front end?

Otherwise i will have to use my decrypt function everywhere in my code when needed.

I cannot use `the_content` filter because it is only working inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `get_posts()` method of the `WP_Query` class (line 3769), you will find out this filter:

```
$this->posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'the_posts', array( $this->posts, &$this ) );
```

It's the very first hook you can use to modify queried posts on both back-end and front-end.

`$this->posts` is an array of queried posts so it's easy to modify the content of each posts for your purposes.

Example, we want to change the first post content:

```
function wpse_modify_post_content($args) {

    $args[0]->post_content = 'This filter filters the content of a post right after it is fetched from the database';

    return $args;

}
add_filter('the_posts', 'wpse_modify_post_content');
```

For specific edit screen, you can use [`content_edit_pre`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_edit_pre) filter. This filter accepts two parameters.

Example:

```
function wpse_content_edit_pre($content, $post_id) {

    $content = 'This filter filters the content of a post which being loaded for editting.';

    return $content;

}
add_filter('content_edit_pre', 'wpse_content_edit_pre', 10, 2);
```

**I recommend you to take a look at [Filter Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)**.

Comment: It seems that it is working only in the frontend...In the backend from the edit post screen it does not work...

Comment: Yeah, I have just updated the answer.

Comment: I am reading that the _edit_pre filters are being phased out (cant find the link now) and replaced by the edit_* hooks...Also instead of the_posts i think that the "posts_results" is also working and i think that it serves the purpose...So i am testing also this combination. Using edit_post_content and posts_results hooks for the task....Will come back with results

Comment: I don't recommend to use `posts_results` hook.

Comment: I read the docs more carefully and i agree with you..I switched to the_posts..Take a look at the other hook , and tell me your opinion ...Are you stil insisi on _edit_pre or not?

Comment: Where did you read about `content_edit_pre` hook? I read it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_edit_pre) and don't find out anything is going to be phased out.

Comment: It was an opinion that is being phased out..I will try to find it again...